# How to tack backup for particular view in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

Recently I created view for services page,Now i want to take mysql backup for that view.i don't want tack hold database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto "admin/config/development/configuration/single/export" and select the view you want to export as shown in below image. It will give you out put in yaml.
 [image: export views in D8]